# Drupal 8 How to fix "URL is Incomplete" error at Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: social-network

When I try to submit my HTML code for Facebook's new Instant Articles, I get the error below. This is the only error I get and it is displayed at the bottom of the pasted code.

URL is Incomplete: The URL used for this media element is missing information. We have automatically filled in information for you. Please check that the URL is now correct and complete.
Any idea how to fix that?

img src="/sit/to/img/" - wont work

img src="http://mydomain.de/path/to/img/"

help me please

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) module should fix this issue for you.

> Pathologic is an input filter which can correct paths in links and images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or the content was moved to a different server. Pathologic can also solve the problem of missing images and broken links in your site’s RSS feeds. See more example use cases on the documentation page.

Comment: Pathologic Did not solve the problem

Comment: Did you configure it properly?

Comment: Probably yes, in the configuration I put the full path, in the filters of the editor it also turned it on, it probably did not help me, I need the same plug-in only for the field image.   sorry for my English

Comment: @АлексейМоргун Have you enabled pathologic filter on /admin/config/content/formats?